# How to use g2o for bundle adjustment

Tags: c++, optimization, graph, g2o

I'm trying to use g2o for refine the 3D points obtained through a multi view system.
I  have obtained the 3D points through triangulation, and for each acquisition I have the relative poses and the 2D features.

I would refine the 3D points using g2o for graph optimization, in order to reduce the reprojection error.

Anyone have experience in it? I saw that there are a great number of types of vertices and edges but I can't understand what are the one that can be the more suitable for my application.

I tried to follow the 'sba_demo.cpp' in the examples folder of g2o but it seems to not use the 2D corresponces.

Comment: Can't speak for g2o, but just in case you're not aware of it, [GTSAM](https://collab.cc.gatech.edu/borg/gtsam?destination=node%2F299) has pretty good documentation and similar capabilities.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try it, unfortunately g2o has a minimal documentation.